# How to explode one column data in many column with defiend range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this input
df :

```
Index    A
0       21
1       16
2       98  
3       18
4       09
5       17
6       15
7       13
8       21
.       .
N        N
```

I would like this in output :

```
Index   A0   A1 .....AN
0       21   17      .
1       16   15      .
2       98   13      .
3       09   21      .
.                    .
.                    .
N                    N
```

N is the number of row by column.
Thank you :)

'' ***

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: are you trying to make a rectangular N\*M DataFrame into a square M\*M DataFrame?

Comment: Actually, those are good questions. How come your final df has still `N` rows?

Comment: I just would like to split one data column to coulmns with defiend range N .for examples split the column that conatain data to columns with 100 rows for each column. thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to reshape the data with numpy.  Note: the values reshape dimensions must multiply into the original dimensions, otherwise numpy will throw an exception:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(2,5)).T.add_prefix('A')

print(df)
   A0  A1
0  21  17
1  16  15
2  98  13
3  18  21
4   9  55
```